# Twilio DataTrack API stop?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

So I'm creating a simple zoom clone app and got an issue with the **DataTrack API**.

**Initialized DataTrack**

```
this.dataTrack = new LocalDataTrack();
```

The issue is that after leaving/disconnecting in the room the record Icon in the browser is still there.

**LeaveRoom func**

```
this.room.localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach((publication) => {
   publication.track.stop();
   publication.unpublish();
});

console.log("this.dataTrack", this.dataTrack); // HOW TO STOP THIS ?
```

Answer (score 2):

The LocalDataTrack object has an id property.

You can get the [MediaStreamTrack](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#mediastreamtrack) by looking up the media stream tracks from the media streams.

```js
const userMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:true});

const tracks = userMedia.then(mediaStreams => {
     const tracks = mediaStreams.getTracks();
     for(let track of tracks) {
         if(track.id === this.dataTrack.id) {
              track.stop();
         }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the 3 I do. Works like a charm.

```
//Remove chromes "your browser is using the camera" icon
track.forEach((track) => track.stop())
room.localParticipant.unpublishTracks(track)
track.forEach((track) => track.detach())
```